# Replace text in one line but avoid certain pattern

Tags: regex, string, sed, replace

I am trying to use `sed`for replacing text in one line but only if it is not inside a specific pattern.
For instance the line could be

> bla blab blab \cite{bla} \cite[prout]{bla} \footcite[prout][hein]{ bla } Bla aBla

and the result must be (by replacing bla by KUI with unsensitive case)

> KUI blab blab \cite{bla} \cite[prout]{bla} \footcite[prout][hein]{ bla } KUI aBla

I am not sure `sed` is the right command for this. Other classical unix command could be used.

Comment: I doubt you can do anything interesting with sed for a language that can have nested curly brackets. *(except if you project to use a bad solution that works half a time)*. A solution with a perl command line is possible.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Do you have any idea of the syntax ?

Comment: You might try with Perl. [Like this](https://ideone.com/dho7W6).

Comment: @Guuk: the language seems to use a kind of latex syntax that allows *tags* to be nested.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte You are right but the purpose of my question is to write a code for automatically add a specific latex command for some words and avoiding to apply it on certain case. On some situation, I want to avoid to add nested tags.

Comment: Yes I know, the problem with this kind of language is situations like `\tag1{ bla \tag2{ bla } bla }`. With a tool like sed, you can't handle these cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sed is for simple s/old/new/, that is all. You aren't simply doing s/old/new/ so you shouldn't be considering sed. Just use awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
function descend( internalStr) {
    while( ++i <= length($0) ) {
        char = substr($0,i,1)
        internalStr = internalStr char
        if (char == "{") {
            internalStr = internalStr descend()
        }
        else if (char == "}") {
            return internalStr
        }
    }
}
BEGIN { IGNORECASE=1 }
{
    fullStr = externalStr = ""
    i = 0
    while( ++i <= length($0) ) {
        char = substr($0,i,1)
        externalStr = externalStr char
        if (char == "{") {
            gsub(/\<bla\>/,"KUI",externalStr)
            fullStr = fullStr externalStr descend()
            externalStr = ""
        }
    }
    gsub(/\<bla\>/,"KUI",externalStr)
    print fullStr externalStr
}
```

.

```
$ cat file
bla blab blab \cite{bla} \cite[prout]{bla} \footcite[prout][hein]{ bla } Bla aBla
bla \tag1{ bla \tag2{ bla } bla } bla

$ gawk -f tst.awk file
KUI blab blab \cite{bla} \cite[prout]{bla} \footcite[prout][hein]{ bla } KUI aBla
KUI \tag1{ bla \tag2{ bla } bla } KUI
```

The above uses GNU awk for word boundaries and IGNORECASE. The need for those can be worked around pretty easily with other awks.

Note that it works even for nested tags (the 2nd input/output line).

Comment: I am not very familiar with `awk` but this is a good opportunity for trying it. Thank you! @edmorton

Answer (score 2):

***gawk*** solution for 1-level enclosing brackets `{...}`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ IGNORECASE=1 }
     {   split($0, a, /\{[^{}]+\}/, seps); 
         for(i=1; i in a; i++) { 
             gsub(/\<bla\>/,"KUI",a[i]); 
             printf "%s%s",a[i],seps[i] 
         } 
         print ""  
     }' file
```

The output:

```
KUI blab blab \cite{bla} \cite[prout]{bla} \footcite[prout][hein]{ bla } KUI aBla
```

Answer (score 1):

#### First variant - works with nested braces.

```
awk -F '' '
    function buf_sub() {
        gsub(/\ybla\y/, "KUI", buffer);
        string = string buffer;
        buffer = "";
    }
    BEGIN {
        IGNORECASE = 1;
    }
    {
        string = "";
        buffer = "";
        for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
            if(cnt) 
                string = string $i; 
             else 
                buffer = buffer $i;
            
            if($i == "{") {
                cnt++;
                buf_sub();
            } 
            if($i == "}") 
                cnt--;  
        }
        buf_sub();
        print string;
    }
' input.txt
```

**Input**

```
bla blab blab \cite{bla} \cite[prout]{bla} \footcite[prout][hein]{ bla } Bla aBla
blab bla blab \cite{bla} \cite[prout]{bla} \footcite[prout][hein]{ bla } aBla Bla
bla \tag1{ bla \tag2{ bla } bla } bla
```

**Output**

```
KUI blab blab \cite{bla} \cite[prout]{bla} \footcite[prout][hein]{ bla } KUI aBla
blab KUI blab \cite{bla} \cite[prout]{bla} \footcite[prout][hein]{ bla } aBla KUI
KUI \tag1{ bla \tag2{ bla } bla } KUI
```

---

#### Second variant - doesn't process braces nesting.

```
sed -r 's/(\\[^}]*})/\n@#\1\n@#/g' input.txt |
sed '/\\/! s/\bbla\b/KUI/gI;' |
sed ':lab; N; $!b lab; s/\n@#//g;'
```

**Input**

```
bla blab blab \cite{bla} \cite[prout]{bla} \footcite[prout][hein]{ bla } Bla aBla
blab bla blab \cite{bla} \cite[prout]{bla} \footcite[prout][hein]{ bla } aBla Bla
```

**Output**

```
KUI blab blab \cite{bla} \cite[prout]{bla} \footcite[prout][hein]{ bla } KUI aBla
blab KUI blab \cite{bla} \cite[prout]{bla} \footcite[prout][hein]{ bla } aBla KUI
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution using perl:**

```
perl -lpe 's/(\\footcite([^}]*)|\\cite([^}]*))(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\bbla\b/KUI/ig' file
```

The `\footcite` and `\cite` commands will be avoid in the replacement process.

Comment: This solution is based on the @CasimiretHippolyte proposition.

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
sed -e 's/\<[bB]la\>/KUI/g' yourFile
```

where:

```
\<bla\>
```

specifies to search a word that match exactly the string 'bla'. `\<` is used to specify the beginning of the word. In this case the word must start with b or B. `\>` specify the ending of the word. In this case it must ends with a. Between 'b' ('B') and 'a', there must be only one 'l'.

**Update**
I noticed that sed do not read well the characters '{' and '}' so it consider a word also {bla} and translates it into {KUI}. 
A workaround, is the following:

```
sed -e 's/{/opened/g' yourFile > newFile
sed -e 's/}/closed/g' newFile1 > yourFile

sed -e 's/\<[bB]la\>/KUI/g' yourFile > newFile

sed -e 's/opened/{/g' newFile > yourFile
sed -e 's/closed/}/g' yourFile > newFile
```

It's not so elegant, but it works.

Hope it helps

Comment: it is not working with `sed` on OSX and with `GNU sed`. The command replaces all occurences

Comment: Obviously, it works if you do not have in your file the strings "opened" and "closed". Anyway, you can choose every string you want to get it works.