# text file -- how to sort adjacent lines that have the same level of indentation

Tags: shell, awk, readline

***UPDATE: The root problem has been solved by fixing a number of Sequelize migrations that always run before mysqldump is called, as discussed in the comments that are below the article that is linked in the next paragraph. However, the core technical challenge is still interesting.***

I have a problem with mysqldump that [might be solved by configuring mysqldump differentl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77944961/mysqldump-no-data-how-to-ensure-consistent-order-of-lines-in-dump-file)y, but probably will be solved by just piping the output through a shell script.

Basically, `mysqldump` always outputs the tables in the same order, but it list all columns (other than `id`) for each table in random order.

So, the first run might output this...

```
create TABLE `ONE` ( 
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `column_a` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `column_b` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `column_c` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
create TABLE `TWO` ( 
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `column_x` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `column_y` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `column_z` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

...and on the second run, it might produce something like this:

```
create TABLE `ONE` ( 
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `column_c` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `column_b` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `column_a` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
create TABLE `TWO` ( 
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `column_y` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `column_x` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `column_z` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I'd like to pipe the result through a shellscript that always sorts the lines in the same way. What script would achieve this? The script needs to run on a build agent that runs on Ubuntu, so if it is possible and practical to use standard GNU tools like `awk` then that would be superior to using custom tools.

Comment: Are you certain about this behavior? I've created a sample database and I ran `mysqldump` in a loop and it always produces columns in the same order. You can see my test [here](https://gist.github.com/larsks/ee1a084aa8ee177f858d9a25c4d4d5d4) (this assumes your sample tables `ONE` and `TWO` have been loaded into a database named `example`).

Comment: Otherwise, this question is probably a dupe of
"[Sort alphabetically lines between 2 patterns in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33947274/sort-alphabetically-lines-between-2-patterns-in-bash)", with pattern 1 as `^CREATE TABLE.*(` and pattern 2 as `^)`.

Comment: Thanks @larks. I'm certain about the behaviour, but it might be a side-effect of recreating the DB and rerunning the migrations between each dump. (See commands on the mysql-orientated version of this post.) I'll check out the answer you linked to above.

Comment: Those solutions are interesting, but all assume there is just one instance of the start pattern and the end pattern 

Comment: Won't the `\`id\`` column wind up after the `\`column\`` entries?

Comment: Thanks all. It turns out the underlying issue was that the migrations that occur before each dump are not always executing every step in the same order. I'll put more details on the other post once I have them.

Comment: please update the question with the code you've tried and the (wrong) results generated by said code

Comment: does the mysqldump output contain anything other than `create table` commands; if 'yes' then consider updating the sample to show some examples

Comment: coming up with a method to sort the sample data should be (relatively) easy but quickly becomes more complicated if we take into consideration a more realistic set of data; for example ... will `PRIMARY KEY` be the only non-column clause? will all columns always have a `(NOT) NULL` clause? will the PK always be a single column named `id`? does the PK column(s) always need to be the first listed column(s) (in which case the `PRIMARY KEY` clause will likely need to be parsed to determine final column order)? will each (non)column clause be on a separate line?

Comment: a cursory glance at [mysql 'create table' syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html) shows we're looking at some major coding if we have to write a comprehensive parser unless we can definitively nail down some rules/expectations on the data we'll be working with ... otherwise it would probably be easier to write some SQL to query the system tables to generate the desired output

Comment: since you mention `awk` ... what is the output from running `awk --version`?

Comment: while not demonstrated in the sample data ... is it possible that a column (single indentation) could have a subordinate/follow-on line with a further indentation and thus need to remain together when sorting the column?  something akin to the `BAKER / 123` pair in [daweo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77947170)

Comment: Regarding "use standard GNU tools" - There are standard tools (as defined by POSIX and will exist on all Unix boxes) and then there are GNU tools (as defined by GNU and will only exist where GNU tools are installed) but there are no standard GNU tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assumptions:

- the input is guaranteed to have a very specific format that follows exactly the sample provided in the question, namely ...
- each clause (of the `create table` command) resides on a separate line (eg, we won't see 2 columns listed on a single line)
- there is only one level of indents
- all column clauses contain the string `NOT NULL` or `NULL`
- we do not sort the column clause containing the string `AUTO-INCREMENT`
- we do not sort the `PRIMARY KEY` clause
- all sortable column clauses show up between the `AUTO-INCREMENT` column clause and the `PRIMARY KEY` clause
- NOTE: we are not going to address any of the slew of other options available with the [mysql 'create table' command](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html), ie, we're not going to build a full-fledged parser

One approach:

- if a line matches the format of a 'sortable column clause' then we add it to an array
- if a line does not match the format of a 'sortable column clause' then we a) dump anything currently in the array to stdout and then b) print the current line to stdout

One `GNU awk` implementation of this approach:

```
awk '
BEGIN                { PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_str_asc"     # sort arrays by value, sorted as string in asc[ending] order
                       delete lines                             # designate variable "lines" as an array
                     }

/^[[:space:]]/    &&                                            # if line starts with white space (ie, it is indented) and ...
!/AUTO_INCREMENT/ &&                                            # line does not contain string "AUTO_INCREMENT" and ...
/ NULL/              { lines[++cnt] = $0                        # line contains a single white space + string "NULL", then save current line in array
                       next                                     # skip to next line of input
                     }

cnt                  { for (i in lines)                         # loop through indices of array in @val_str_asc sorted order
                           print lines[i]                       # print array value to stdout
                       delete lines                             # reset array
                       cnt = 0                                  # reset counter (aka array index)
                     }
1                                                               # print current line of input to stdout
' sample.sql
```

**NOTES:**

- `sample.sql` is an exact copy of the 2nd pair of `create table` commands from OP's question (ie, the example with the out-of-order `column_X` rows)
- requires `GNU awk` for `PROCINFO["sort_in"]` support which in turn is used to sort the contents of the array; see [gawk predefined sorting orders](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html) for details

This generates:

```
create TABLE `ONE` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
  `column_a` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `column_b` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `column_c` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
create TABLE `TWO` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `column_x` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `column_y` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `column_z` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: tested and confirmed that this works 

Answer (score 1):

GNU AWK

```
awk '
    /AUTO_INCREMENT,$/ || /^ *PRIMARY KEY/{blk=!blk;}
    /AUTO_INCREMENT,$/ {print}
    blk{a[$0]; next}
    {
        n=asorti(a,b)
        for(i=1; i<=n; i++) print b[i]
        delete a
    }1
' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't REALLY want to compare `id` and `PRIMARY_KEY` against `column_a` etc. (as you would do if you were really sorting all the lines at a given indentation level) as that'd be comparing apples to oranges, then you could just sort the lines that match some regexp or are between lines that match 2 regexps, e.g. using any `awk` and any `sort` we could sort the lines containing `COLLATE`:

```
$ awk '/COLLATE/{print | "sort"; next} {close("sort")} 1' file
create TABLE `ONE` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `column_a` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `column_b` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `column_c` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
create TABLE `TWO` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `column_x` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `column_y` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `column_z` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

or the lines between each AUTO_INCREMENT ... PRIMARY KEY pair:

```
$ awk '
    /PRIMARY KEY/    { f=0; close("sort") }
    { if (f) print | "sort"; else print }
    /AUTO_INCREMENT/ { f=1 }
' file
create TABLE `ONE` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `column_a` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `column_b` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `column_c` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
create TABLE `TWO` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `column_x` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `column_y` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `column_z` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

With GNU awk for `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` if there can be no duplicate lines in a block of `COLLATE` lines we could do:

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN { PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc" }
    /COLLATE/ { vals[$0]; next }
    { for (val in vals) print val; delete vals; print }
' file
create TABLE `ONE` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `column_a` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `column_b` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `column_c` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
create TABLE `TWO` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `column_x` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `column_y` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `column_z` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

or with GNU awk for `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` if there can be duplicate lines in a block of `COLLATE` lines:

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN { PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_str_asc" }
    /COLLATE/ { vals[length(vals)+1] = $0; next }
    { for (i in vals) print vals[i]; delete vals; print }
' file
create TABLE `ONE` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `column_a` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `column_b` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `column_c` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
create TABLE `TWO` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `column_x` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `column_y` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `column_z` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

The first command spawns a subshell to call `sort` once per block of `COLLATE` lines while the GNU version doesn't spawn any subshells so it'll be faster but not as portable.

Answer (score 0):

> how to sort adjacent lines that have the same level of indentation

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
ABLE
  CHARLIE
  BAKER
    123
  EASY
  DOG
  FOX
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_str_asc";indent=-1}{match($0,/[^[:space:]]/)}RSTART==indent{arr[NR]=$0;next}{indent=RSTART;for(i in arr){print arr[i]};delete arr;arr[NR]=$0}END{for(i in arr){print arr[i]}}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
ABLE
  BAKER
  CHARLIE
    123
  DOG
  EASY
  FOX
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that [Scanning Order](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html) should be values-as-strings, ascending and set to `indent` to `-1` (value never reached). For each line I use [`match` string function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) to detect indent size, by finding position of 1st non-white-space character. If indent is same as previous I only add current line to array `arr` under key being number of line, otherwise I save indent size in variable `indent`, output all from array in predefined order, cleanse array (so it become empty) and add current line to array. After all lines are processed (`END`) I output content of array `arr`.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*

Comment: for your sample data it appears that `123` is associated with `BAKER` so in the sorted output I would expect `123` to remain with `BAKER` (as opposed to moving to `CHARLIE`)

Comment: if you run your code against OP's sample data this code will generate a syntactically invalid `create table` command (ie, `PRIMARY KEY` (does not go at top of list) then `column_a` - `column_c` (correctly sorted) then `id` (with trailing comma but no follow on clause)

Comment: consider reformatting the `awk` script for easier readability; a quick-n-dirty method: `awk -o- 'current_awk_script'`

Comment: This looks to be very close to a solution. When I run it against my actual dump.sql, it sorts the lines that I mentioned need sorting. This reveals that issue mentioned by @markp-fuso that the trailing commas are now not on the correct lines. Also, it sorts the `PRIMARY_KEY` line, which needs to keep its current location. (BTW I've solved this problem in ways that are more MySQL focused that text manipulation focused, but hopefully this discussion is still interesting and useful.)

Comment: You'd need to implement a recursive-descent parser (or write a convoluted solution with loops, variables, and arrays to mimic the functionality that recursion provides) to solve the problem described in this answer as you need to iteratively sort parent+descendants blocks from deepest indent to highest to avoid child `123` moving from it's parent `BAKER` to `CHARLIE`. There's examples of recursive functions written in awk at https://stackoverflow.com/a/46063483/1745001, https://stackoverflow.com/a/42736174/1745001, and  https://stackoverflow.com/a/32020697/1745001 if you're interested.